# How to setup makefile in windows

Tags: linux, windows, makefile, cygwin

I tried to download cygwin to run my makefile but I get the following error:

```
> make
FIND: formato del parametro non corretto
FIND: formato del parametro non corretto
g++  -o esempio
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
makefile:12: recipe for target 'esempio' failed
make: *** [esempio] Error 1
```

This is my basic makefile:

```
PHONY: all clean

CPPSOURCES += $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')

clean:
    rm esempio

all: esempio
    @true

esempio: $(CPPSOURCES)
    g++ $(CPPSOURCES) -o esempio
```

what can I do to fix it?

Comment: error message like `FIND:` indicates (to me) that it is trying to run the MS-Windows `FIND`, not a *nix `find`. Edit your Q to show the output of running `echo $PATH` from the same terminal window that produce the error messages above. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Two things look unusual to me. First is this:

```
CPPSOURCES += $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
```

You usually use `wildcard` instead of `find`. I would change it to the following:

```
CPPSOURCES = $(sort $(wildcard *.cpp))
CPPOBJECTS = $(CPPSOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

Second, for your `esempio` recipe, use `CPPOBJECTS` instead of `CPPSOURCES`:

```
esempio: $(CPPOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPOBJECTS) -o esempio
```

The use of `true` in one recipe also looks kind of odd (but it appears to work). You could change it to the following and move it to the top of the file so it is the default recipe:

```
.PHONY: all
all esempio: $(CPPOBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPOBJECTS) -o esempio
```

[Here](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) is an example of a makefile that uses a lot of GNU extra features.

Comment: See `make` info at  `6.6 Appending More Text to Variables` for += usage

Comment: Thanks @matzeri. I take that back... I have used the operator. I updated the answer to remove the statement.

Comment: 1. Ty for suggestion of using .o for build!
2. wildcard does't work
3. I find a "solution", renaming cygwin find > find2 and use find2

Answer (score 1):

You have the dos command directory ahead of the cygwin bin directory in the PATH.
This is my cygwin path:

```
$ echo $PATH
$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Go/bin:/bin
```

The only windows directory is the golang bin directory. Use `cygpath` the find the cygwin equivalent directory name.

The simplest way to do this is to remove all windows directories and only add back the few you need. To do this, modify your user environment variables to add `CYGWIN_NOWINPATH=1`. In your `.bashrc` you can add back the cygwin equivalent for only those windows directories that you find you really need.